# Left Join on association table

Tags: mysql

I need help trying to join a table that uses an association table.

I have a users table

```
Users Table
user_id
user_name

Association Table
user_id
project_id

Project Table
project_id
project_name
```

I need to pull a user and the count of projects they are associated with.

```
SELECT u.user_name, COUNT(p.project_id) projects
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN association a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_name
```

How do I associate the two tables?

Comment: The query should work as is (although it can be improved a little). What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to associate projects and users, you need to do 2 joins:

```
SELECT u.user_name, COUNT(p.project_id) projects
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN association a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN projects p ON p.project_id = a.project_id
GROUP BY u.user_name
```

If you want it faster you can do:

```
SELECT u.user_name, COUNT(a.project_id) projects
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN association a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_name
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but did not sped up my page cause the joins were more complicated so its time was longer than sum of individual queries. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like:

```
SELECT
    Utbl.user_name,
    NumTbl.numProjects
FROM
    UsersTable Utbl,
    (SELECT 
         Atbl.user_id, 
         COUNT(*) AS numProjects
     FROM 
         ProjectTable Ptbl,
         AssociationTable Atbl
     WHERE
         Utbl.user_id = Atbl.user_id AND
         Atbl.project_id = Ptbl.project_id) NumTbl
WHERE
    Utbl.user_id = NumTbl.user_id
```